# How to write a method extension for a static Class in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, extension-methods, static-classes

I would like to add a custom `WriteColoredText` method to the `Console` Class, to acces like this:

```
Console.WriteColoredText(Parametters)
```

The problem is that I only found information about creating method extensions for specific datatypes but any about a method extension for a Class.

If this is not possibly, which similar alternatives I have?

Comment: That is not possible.  You need to make your own module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't.

[Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) can only apply to object instances, but the [`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is static. The only solution is to write your own, completely separate class, say `ConsoleEx`, and implement any methods you want there.

> Extension methods make it possible to write a method that can be called as if it were **an instance method** of the existing type.

Comment: This is giving me a new idea but I don't know if this is possibly, Imagine that I write that ConsoleExtended class, I could add easier ALL the Console class methods to my custom class? if you preffer i can create a new question for this but please if you could just answer a simply yes/no by the moment I will appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Sure, your `ConsoleExtended` class can use any methods you want in the `Console` class. Then in your own project you can just use your custom class wherever you would rather take advantage of the new methods.

Comment: I can't find the way to add those native methods to my class together the custom methods, I'm gonna make a new question, thanks again for the info.

Comment: @ElektroStudios You'd still have to write the class name, i.e. `Console.WriteLine` (or whatever) within your custom class. And you'd still have to wrap every method of `Console` which you want to be able to call like `ConsoleExtended.WriteLine`.